# jQuery check for window resize triggers toggle too many times

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that I only want to work when the window is smaller then 768px. (this is for a responsive site so I can't just do it for mobile devices)

I have some code that checks for a specific css style only applied when the screen size is less then 768px. Then it hides the menu and toggles the menu when a user clicks on another item. (#mainMenu)

I have the following code:

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($('#mainLogo').css('float') == 'none') {
        $('.menu-main-menu-container').slideToggle();   
        } else {
        $('.menu-main-menu-container').slideDown();
    }   
}

$('#mainMenu').click(function() {
       checkSize();
});
```

This code works pretty well except for when users are on a desktop and have the screen smaller then 768px, toggle the menu closed, and then drag the screen wider. It keeps the main menu hidden.

I tried adding this:

```
$(window).resize(checkSize);
```

But now when I resize the screen, both smaller and wider, it toggles the menu about 5 times.

Is there a way to fix this? Or maybe a better way to check for the width of the screen so that the toggle only happens when the screen is smaller then 768px? I wish there were media queries for jQuery!

(ps I also tried looking at the window width but it isn't accurate enough)

Comment: If your articulation point occurs between mobile and everything else, why sniff for resolution as opposed to mobile device? Also, not sure why -1 I think this is perfectly acceptable question..

Comment: `resize()` triggers while the window is resizing, it's not "resized".  You could implement this via a `debounce` which would trigger when the user stops resizing, but you'll still get the same issue in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the CSS-mediaqueries-way aside (but i see your idea here) it would be possible to just put your code inside a if statement. in your case:

```
if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {  .... }
```

which would look like:

```
function checkSize(){
   if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
        $('.menu-main-menu-container').slideToggle();   
   } else {
        $('.menu-main-menu-container').slideDown();
   }   
}
```

Comment: since window.width might be not accurate enough, check this:
https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/issues/468#issuecomment-23626238